# geodesic of infinite length without self-intersections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm curious, does a geodesic of infinite length without self-intersections exist in a Riemannian manifold (M, g) which has finite diameter? There shouldn't be one rigth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with irrational slope, then its image in the flat two torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a geodesic that never intersects itself and has infinite length.